# Trigger check for column values changed to specific values and make updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to reate a trigger to check for the column changed to specific values and make specific updates for each value. How do I assign the changed value to a variable and compare it with if statements to make the correct update? Now the message displays "The multi-part identifier "inserted.Status" could not be bound"

```
    CREATE TRIGGER status_updates ON CONTACT1
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS

    DECLARE 
    @Status nvarchar(6) = inserted.Status 

    --Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure status_updates, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 1021]
    --The multi-part identifier "inserted.Status" could not be bound.

    If @Status  = '52'
    BEGIN
        --Make Updates for code 52

    UPDATE P
    SET
         P.First_Name = T.ForeName
        ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
        ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
    FROM SIS.dbo.People P
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.KEY4 = P.People_ID
    CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
    WHERE i.Key1 = '52'
    AND P.PEOPLE_ID = i.KEY4

    END

    If @Status  = '53'
    BEGIN
        --Make Updates for code 53

    UPDATE P
    SET
         P.First_Name = T.ForeName
        ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
        ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
    FROM SIS.dbo.People P
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.KEY4 = P.People_ID
    CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
    WHERE i.Key1 = '53'
    AND P.PEOPLE_ID = i.KEY4

    END

    If @Status  = '54'
    BEGIN
        --Make Updates for code 54

    UPDATE P
    SET
         P.First_Name = T.ForeName
        ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
        ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
    FROM SIS.dbo.People P
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.KEY4 = P.People_ID
    CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
    WHERE i.Key1 = '55'
    AND P.PEOPLE_ID = i.KEY4;

    END

    If @Status  = '55'
    BEGIN
        --Make Updates for code 55

INSERT INTO SIS.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
SELECT
     T.ForeName
    ,T.Middle_Name
    ,T.Surname
FROM inserted i --change to inserted
INNER JOIN SIS.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = i.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
WHERE i.Key1 = '55'

    END

    GO
```

Comment: it might be that it's not object oriented so i have to assign it with a select statement. @Status nvarchar(6) = (SELECT STATUS FROM inserted). is it better to use the if statements so that each query doesn't have to run, and only the query to update the changed code will run?

Comment: `declare @Status NVarChar(6) = inserted.Status` assumes: (1) that there is a single value of `Status` and (b) that you can retrieve the value from `inserted` without a `select`. Since triggers fire once per statement and a single statement may affect many rows, something has to change. You can dispense with `@Status` if the subsequent operations check in `on` or `where` clauses for the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER status_updates ON CONTACT1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE P
    SET
         P.First_Name = T.ForeName
        ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
        ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
    FROM SIS.dbo.People P
    INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON i.KEY4 = P.People_ID
    CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
    WHERE (i.Key1 = '52' AND i.[Status] = '52')
    OR (i.Key1 = '53' AND i.[Status] = '53')
    OR (i.Key1 = '54' AND i.[Status] = '54') 

    INSERT INTO SIS.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
    SELECT
         T.ForeName
        ,T.Middle_Name
        ,T.Surname
    FROM inserted i --change to inserted
    INNER JOIN SIS.dbo.People P
        ON P.People_ID = i.Key4
    CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
    WHERE i.Key1 = '55'
    AND i.Status = '55'
GO
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like what i'm trying to do. So, is it redundant to have if statements. Does the sql evaluate the where first before executing the query?

Comment: Yes, the where clause is executed before the set clause.

Comment: @ERPise The logical order of processing for a `select` statement is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx#Logical%20Processing%20Order%20of%20the%20SELECT%20statement). Other statements follow a similar order.